# How to bypass CheckedListBox characters limit?

Tags: c#, winforms, limit, checkedlistbox

I have data that has 1250+ items (rows) and when I pasted it inside the CheckedListBox Items I noticed that not all data copied. I tried to write something inside to check if there was problem with copy paste but no, I just couldn't add more characters. I used NotePad++ to count the characters and it showed 30 811 so the limit is 30811 characters but I want to add more what I can do?

Comment: Why don't you use a DataGridView ?

Comment: @AbZy I don't know, I never used it. Can it do the same?

Comment: It doesn't have check boxes by default, but you could add a checkbox column. [see this tutorial](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/adv_winforms_5.htm)

Comment: @AbZy cool but you sure it doesn't have such limit?

Comment: I think 1250+ rows are considered ok for DataGridView. Try and let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckedListBox was never meant as a substitute for tables, nor as a wrapper for ~1250 rows... As you've been suggested in comments, use a different control, like `DataGridView` or maybe `ListView` (if it makes sense in your scenario).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx